# confidence interval for proportion

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

Suppose $k$ events were observed in $n$ trials. We then have $\hat{p} = k/n$ and the standard Wald confidence interval is

$$\hat{p} \pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n}$$

I wonder why the biased estimate of standard deviation is used instead of the unbiased version $\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/(n-1)}$?

Comment: *Both* estimates are biased.  However, $\hat p(1-\hat p)/n$ is unbiased for the *variance* when $k$ is assumed to have a Binomial distribution.  Moreover, given that $\pm z_{\alpha/2}$ is already a gross approximation to the correct multiples when $n$ is small (and when $n$ is large there's no appreciable difference between $\sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt{n-1}$), why would it even matter?

Comment: @whuber, again, this looks like a fairly complete answer to the question.

Comment: @Glen_b My comment was a request for clarification concerning the point of the question.  It is difficult to provide a clear answer to any question that appears to be predicated on false assumptions, so--given that these assumptions are incorrect--I would like to know whether respondents should address that issue or whether Peter would like to modify the question accordingly.